# triggering video on click doesn't not play all the time?

Tags: javascript, load, html5-video, playback

Here is my situation:

I have lot of video each playing in a different lightbox.

WHen opennign the lightbox, I trigger the video by clicking a play button overlaying. Which start the video fine using the below:

```
    $('a.trigger-video-play').parent().click(function () {
    $(this).children("video")[0].play()
    $('a.trigger-video-play').fadeOut('slow')
    $(this).children('#video-play').attr('controls', true);
    $($('a.trigger-video-play').get(0)).show();
    $('.lightbox-background').addClass('pause');
    $(this).children("video").addClass('topause')
    });
```

The line belog beign the one triggering the video to play:

```
    $(this).children("video")[0].play()
```

On clicking outside the lightbox, I"m using this code to:

```
    $('.lightbox-background').click(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    $('#halo-one.lightbox-outbox').fadeOut('slow');
    $('.lightbox-outbox').fadeOut('slow');
    $('a.trigger-video-play').fadeIn('slow')

    $("video").each(function () {
        this.pause(this.load())
    })
    $("#video-play").each(function () {
        $(this).attr('controls', false);
    })
    jQuery.each($("iframe.web"), function () {
        $(this).attr({
            src: $(this).attr("src")
        });
    });
});
```

1/ stopping the video and make it start from zero ( this way when the user came back, the video will play from zero):

```
$("video").each(function () {
        this.pause(this.load())
    })
```

The problem I'm having is sometime, when the user trigger the video to play, the video is not playing. The user have to touch/ drag a little bit the control bar to make the video play !! and this is very random.

I"m wondering if it s a clash du with the second function which use load or not ?

Does anyone has some advice ?

It will be super.

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your method

```
this.pause(this.load())
```

Try to use:

```
$("video").each(function () {
    this.pause();
    this.currentTime = 0;  //make currenttime 0 to start from beginning
})
```